# Maven stops working from terminal after macOS Catalina update: there is no POM in this directory

Tags: macos, maven, macos-catalina

After updating to Catalina I get the following error when running `mvn clean install` from the terminal:

```
 The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/private/var/folders/xs/lgy9yxv501xcvnqr_zhg85wr0000gn/T/hsperfdata_user1). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
```

The current directory contains a pom.xml and a valid project

```
user1@xyz project1 % pwd
/Users/user1/Documents/project/project1
user1@xyz project1 % ls
README.md            pom.xml                project1-service
```

I've tried `mvn clean install -f pom.xml`  as well. This will error with:

```
The project  (/Users/user1/Documents/project/project1/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM /Users/user1/Documents/project/project1/pom.xml: /Users/user1/Documents/project/project1/pom.xml (Operation not permitted)
```

This works just fine from InteliJ's terminal.
Any idea what happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to `System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Full Disk Access` and add Terminal there. Apparently with Catalina you have to manually grant access to apps that access user files.

Comment: My terminal already had full access and I still got the same problem.

Comment: @Roxana Roman, did you add other apps to 'Full Disk Access'? As like ATrubka in my case neither reinstall nor adding to Full Disk Access helped to get mvn clean install running in Terminal. ..

Comment: For me it was not enough giving full disk access, I also had to add terminal to `System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Developer Tools`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but the cause of it was different.
My maven was installed outside of usual directories under `/apps/`.
The system upgrade wiped everything it didn't see appropriate. All custom directories were simply gone. Maven had to be re-installed using `brew install maven`.

UPDATE:

The files haven't been deleted. Instead, they've been relocated to `/Users/Shared/Previously Relocated Items`, which prevents executables from being found, but the files are not completely lost. You can take what you need from that folder, but in case of maven you can just delete it and install anew using brew with my instruction above.

Here's the explanation for why Catalina has done it: https://www.macrumors.com/guide/relocated-items/

Answer (score 0):

for Mac users:
you need to make sure to do this so it builds the right directory:
   mvn -f path/to/pom.xml  ...
and then give the access to files and folders to java and terminal from the security&privacy option in system preferences